# Jquery + Javascript + php

Tags: jquery

My javascript button calls a javascript function which inside the function there is ajax and ajax calls a php script file, and the php file writes to a text file.

My problem, locally everything works the php written in an OK file. on the other hand when I put on the web site the behavior changes the result the ajax function which calls a php script file no longer writes or is triggered.

Buttons :

```
<li><a href="javascript:callfunction('button Offre De Service');">Offre De Services</a></li>
```

et

```
<a href="javascript:callfunctions('connexionsecure','button Connection Secure');" class="bouton_rouge2">Connexion Sécurisée/Secure <img src="images/flecheblanchedroite.png" alt="flecheblanchedroite02" /></a>
```

Here is my javascript and ajax script:

```js
/**
 * Call Function
 */
function callfunction(id_logbutton) 
{
    location="fr_offre_de_services.php";
    logbutton(id_logbutton);

}

/**
 * Call Functions
 */
function callfunctions(id_toggle,id_logbutton) 
{
    toggle(id_toggle);
    logbutton(id_logbutton);

}

/**
 * Show or hide an page element...
 */
function toggle(id)
{
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  var elem2 = document.getElementById("connexionsecure");
  var elem3 = document.getElementById("systemcaisse");
        
  if (elem.style.display == "none") {
    elem.style.display = "block";
    
  }
  else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  if (elem2.style.display == "block" && elem3.style.display == "block") {
      if (id == "connexionsecure") elem3.style.display = "none";
      if (id == "systemcaisse") elem2.style.display = "none";
  }
  
}

/**
 * Connexionsecure...
 */
function logbutton(id)
{
    // See logsecure.php
    // var VarJSCRIPT = 5;
    // $.get("logsecure.php", {VarPHP: VarJSCRIPT});
    
    if (location.protocol == "https:")
    {
        if (id == "button Connection Secure") $.post("logbutton.php", {logbutton: "https Button Connection Secure"}, alert("TEST NCS http... "));
        if (id == "button Offre De Service") $.post("logbutton.php", {logbutton: "https Button Offre De Service"}, alert("TEST ODS https... "));
    }
    else if (location.protocol == "http:")
    {
        if (id == "button Connection Secure") $.post("logbutton.php", {logbutton: "http Button Connection Secure"}, alert("TEST BCS http... "));
        if (id == "button Offre De Service") $.post("logbutton.php", {logbutton: "http Button Offre De Service"}, alert("TEST ODS http... "));
    }

}
```

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
$button = $_POST["logbutton"];
//echo "Display : " .$button;
$file_log=fopen("1234/logbutton.txt", "a+");        
if($file_log == false) die("La création du fichier a échoué");
$date_log = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");    
$log = "Log Button --> " .$button. " " .$date_log."\r\n";   
fwrite($file_log, $log);
fclose($file_log);  
exit();
```

?>

If someone has an idea

cordially

Comment: Perhaps the settings from your PHP-server must changed to do so.

Comment: I don't understand locally it works and on the web with firefox and chromium it works

Comment: And when it doesn't work on web (if it works with Firefox and Chromium)?

Comment: give it a try my site is www.system-caisse.com click on connection secure and then you do www.system-caisse.com/1234 and then click see log button if you see this message in the log "http Button Connection Secure" with your date and time it worked

Comment: On your connection secure there is just a link to https://www.system-caisse.com without `/1234`. If I click there then there is something with your Certificate on your site https://www.system-caisse.com It doesn't works correct.

Comment: The click secure button triggers a write event with php. just the click button is for log if the button has been clicked

the drop-down list of the secure button is irrelevant

To check if the writing has taken place you have to go to www.system-caisse.com/1234 and choose "see log button" to see if the click button has been done.